# Flag popup is broken on election page for narrow screens

Tags: bug, design, flags, election, responsive-design

Flagging the candidate is almost impossible on the [election page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/5?tab=election) on narrow screens. See the animation below:

> [image]

At the same time, flagging for a regular Q&A post works fine.

> [image]

Comment: It looks like when you expand the text it shows the flagging as normal.